# How align elements in a HTML table

Tags: html

I need to create an HTML table that contains the following information

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Paper image | paper image | Paper Image |
| Authors | Authors | Authors |
| Conference | Conference | Conference |
| Link to Download | Link to Download | Link to Download |

I wrote the following code snippet:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="filters-content" style="width: 800px; height: 500px; overflow: auto;">
            <div class="scrollingDiv">
                <div class="container">
                    <table class="table" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 33.33%; padding: 10px;">
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                                        <img src="images/25599.jpg" alt="Paper 1" class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
                                        <div class="mt-2 text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Authors: long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long longlist of Authors</div>
                                        <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Conference: conference name</div>
                                        <div class="mt-2"><a href="papers/C1.pdf" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 16px;">Download paper</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 33.33%; padding: 10px;">
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                                        <img src="images/25599.jpg" alt="Paper 2" class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
                                        <div class="mt-2 text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Authors:  Author1, Author 2</div>
                                        <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Conference: conference 2</div>
                                        <div class="mt-2"><a href="papers/C2.pdf" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 16px;">Download paper</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 33.33%; padding: 10px;">
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                                        <img src="images/25599.jpg" alt="Paper 3" class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
                                        <div class="mt-2 text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Authors: long list of Authors</div>
                                        <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Conference: Conference 3</div>
                                        <div class="mt-2"><a href="papers/c3.pdf" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 16px;">Download paper</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

However, the elements inside the table are not correctly aligned (especially the buttons)[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Put the details in separate row i.e tr like how the image is rendering here.To have borders remove the border:none inside style tag

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">    
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    table tr td {
        border: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body class="mat-typography factory-theme">
    <div class="filters-content" style="width: 800px; height: 500px; overflow: auto;">
        <div class="scrollingDiv">
            <div class="container">
                <table class="table" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 33.33%; padding: 10px;">
                                <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                                    <img src="images/25599.jpg" alt="Paper 1" class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
                                    <div class="mt-2 text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Authors: long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long longlist of Authors</div>
                                    <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Conference: conference name</div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 33.33%; padding: 10px;">
                                <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                                    <img src="images/25599.jpg" alt="Paper 2" class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
                                    <div class="mt-2 text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Authors:  Author1, Author 2</div>
                                    <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Conference: conference 2</div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 33.33%; padding: 10px;">
                                <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                                    <img src="images/25599.jpg" alt="Paper 3" class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
                                    <div class="mt-2 text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Authors: long list of Authors</div>
                                    <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Conference: Conference 3</div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="mt-2"><a href="papers/C1.pdf" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 16px;">Download paper</a></div>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="mt-2"><a href="papers/C2.pdf" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 16px;">Download paper</a></div>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="mt-2"><a href="papers/c3.pdf" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 16px;">Download paper</a></div>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You don't have to create new row, just use `height:100%;` and `justify-content:space-between` or boostrap classname `justify-content-between`.

The reason for the alignment is all the three card does not have equal height, so if we set the height equal and some flex property we can achieve easily.Below i added `height:100%` for some elements.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="filters-content" style="width: 800px; height: 500px; overflow: auto;">
            <div class="scrollingDiv">
                <div class="container">
                    
                    <table class="table" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
                        <tbody style="height: 100%;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 33.33%; padding: 10px;height: 100%;">
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-between" style='height:100%;'>
                                        <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/book-composition-with-open-book_23-2147690555.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg" alt="Paper 1" class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
                                        <div class="mt-2 text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Authors: long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long longlist of Authors</div>
                                        <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Conference: conference name</div>
                                        <div class="mt-2"><a href="papers/C1.pdf" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 16px;">Download paper</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 33.33%; padding: 10px;height: 100%;">
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-between" style='height:100%;'>
                                        <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/book-composition-with-open-book_23-2147690555.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg" alt="Paper 2" class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
                                        <div class="mt-2 text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Authors:  Author1, Author 2</div>
                                        <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Conference: conference 2</div>
                                        <div class="mt-2"><a href="papers/C2.pdf" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 16px;">Download paper</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 33.33%; padding: 10px;height: 100%;">
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-between" style='height:100%;'>
                                        <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/book-composition-with-open-book_23-2147690555.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg" alt="Paper 3" class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
                                        <div class="mt-2 text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Authors: long list of Authors</div>
                                        <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 16px;">Conference: Conference 3</div>
                                        <div class="mt-2"><a href="papers/c3.pdf" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 16px;">Download paper</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage of the table layout.

Here, your code is overloaded with a lot of useless div tags. Use multiple `<tr>` tags to get uniform lines.

Also, try to set css styles in a CSS file, instead of using inline styling.

You will have a cleaner code, with more readability.

I wrote a simplified code on this fiddle that should match your expectations : https://jsfiddle.net/9xhmkLdy/

Answer (score -5):

try

```
  <style>
            div{
                height : 70px;
            }
     </style>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You realize this applies to every single div element on the page, right?